# Blazor : call a method without button click

Tags: c#, blazor

I am learning Razor. I have a very simple Razor component (using MudBlazor framework) in `Budget.razor`

```
@page "/budget"

<PageTitle>Budget</PageTitle>

<MudGrid>
    <MudItem xs="12" sm="6" md="4">
        <p> Hello you @HelloConsole() </p>
        </MudItem>
</MudGrid>
```

and a partial class in `Budget.razor.cs` :

```
namespace MyProject.Pages
{
   public partial class Budget
    {
        protected void HelloConsole()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello");
        }
    }
}
```

I receive the error in Visual studio :

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'object'
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I don’t know about blazor, but I think method you should change to method to `protected string HelloConsole(){return “Hello;”}`

Comment: I really want to understand why it does not work without changing the actual implementation

Comment: Because with the existing implementation it expects the method to return something and by default it’s object. And it’s value will be rendered at runtime. Your current method is return void not any object

Comment: Where in my implementation can I see it expects an object ? Or is it somewhere in Blazor's implementation ?

Comment: Line which has `@HelloConsole` is calling the `HelloConsole` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<p> Hello you @HelloConsole() </p>
```

Says put the output from the method `HelloConsole()` here.  But `HelloConsole` returns a void - exactly what the error says - which the renderer can't handle.

This works:

```
protected string HelloConsole()
{
   Console.WriteLine("Hello");
   return "I just wrote to the console";
}
```

#### Add on to answer:

To execute some code when loading the component:

```
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
   Console.WriteLine("Hello");
}
// or

protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
   Console.WriteLine("Hello");
   return Task.CompletedTask;

}
```

Comment: so the `@` directive does not mean "execute this" ?

Comment: The render process will display whatever it's pointed at.  If it's a property it will call the getter, if its a field it will output the field, if it's a method it will call the method and display the return value.  It expects an object and will display it as a string.

Comment: Ok so there is no possibility in blazor to just say "execute this" without expecting anything else? I understand it's quite theoritical but given I stumble across that, I want to take the opportunity to really get it

Comment: Sure, if you want it to just run code then you can put that logic inside any of the lifecycle events, like `OnInitialized`. If you want something to work with the templating, it needs to provide something the renderer can interpret.

Documentation on lifecycle events may be helpful for you here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-6.0#component-initialization-oninitializedasync

Comment: @FenryrMKIII see my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute as annonymous lambda otherwise it will expect a string/object return:

This should work:

```html
@page "/budget"

<PageTitle>Budget</PageTitle>

<MudGrid>
    <MudItem xs="12" sm="6" md="4">
        <p> Hello you @(() => HelloConsole()) </p>
        </MudItem>
</MudGrid>
```

```cs
protected void HelloConsole()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are writing to the console. The Blazor markup expects an object (because it basically render a set of string). Change the code to return "Hello". That will work.